# Pebble.js WatchApp displays: "Disconnected - run the pebble phone app"

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-js

I can't find much documentation around this issue.  All other running apps on my pebble have a connection to my phone, and work as expected.  However, a Pebble.js application I'm currently working on simply displays `Disconnected - run the pebble phone app`.

I have noticed that in my *Developer Settings* that the Connection Manager is listed as `Disconnected`.  Is this part of the problem?  I see nothing in the logs.

For reference, the application is doing a simple ajax request and displaying the result.

Comment: What is the name of your app? I had a question mark in the `longName` and `shortName` for my app. For some reason Android couldn't handle that and it broke the app. I contacted the PebbleJS developer and he fixed the bug, and it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is often caused by the JavaScript crashing on the phone (undefined reference, unknown function, etc) and so the watch thinks it is not running.

Some ideas to debug this:

- Replace your code with one very simple `console.log("hello world")` statement and see if this works.
- Look at the Logs (`View Logs` button in CloudPebble or `pebble logs` on the command line).
- Very rarely, on Android, I have seen situation where the Pebble app is in a bad state where it cannot execute the JS for only one app. When this happens, you need to force-kill the Pebble app and relaunch it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I almost feel like it's your last bullet point. Is there a good way to force kill the app?

Comment: What I do on my Nexus 5 is: Press the "Windows" (or Tasks) button on the bottom right on the screen to get the list of all the apps currently running; long press on the Pebble app; click "App Info"; click "Force Stop". This is the only way that I know works well.

Comment: That seems to help this along.  Restarting the watch in coordination with that seems to usually do the trick.

Comment: If that happens often, and/or if you have a way to reproduce this we would really appreciate you sending your source code and information on reproducing this to devsupport@getpebble.com - It will help fix the bug! thanks!

Comment: Hey @sarfata - I will get around to that sometime in the next few days here.  I don't have exact steps to reproduce, but it happened very often, mostly after deploying once or twice.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same experience.

I usually kill and restart the pebble app on my phone and then I also do refresh the browser. Sometimes you have to log out of and then log back into Cloudpebble.