# How can I make a pebble.js app that runs without pebble's phone app running?

Tags: javascript, pebble-watch, cloudpebble, pebble-js

I have made an app that runs fine on the pebble when the phone is connected and the pebble app is running, but when the pebble app on the phone is closed, the app crashes, doesn't start and gives the error that it is "Disconnected - Run the phone app", until the pebble app is restarted. The app is in pebble.js and doesn't connect to the internet or use any of the phone's APIs, and therefore shouldn't need to connect to the phone's app. How can I make my app run without the pebble app running?

The source code is [here, on pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/Sqie17Bg)

Note that this question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746475/pebble-js-watchapp-displays-disconnected-run-the-pebble-phone-app)

Comment: The js is running in a sandbox in the phone app. I'm going to guess that what you're trying to do breaks the design paradigm pebble has created. You're going to have to write your js in C which runs on the watch directly. (I'll note that I haven't developed for my pebble in a year or so, so my understanding may be outdated.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rewrite your application in C. This is currently the only way to write Pebble apps that run without a phone.